# Align link to bottom of div and center it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a link stick to the bottom center of a div and have it be centered.

So far I've come up with this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/r494Lx0r/2/

```
div.container {
position: relative;
height: 110px;
width: 120px;
border: dashed 1px red;
}

div.container div.text {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Now how do I make it so that it's centered? I've tried adding `text-align:center;` and `margin:0 auto;` to the container but neither of those do anything.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** add `text-algin: center` to the parent to center the anchor and set `border: solid 1px black;` to your anchor:

```css
div.container {
 position: relative;
 height: 110px;
 width: 120px;
 border: dashed 1px red;
}

div.container div.text {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

a{border: solid 1px black;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="text">
  <a href="#">Google.com</a>
 </div>

</div>
```

Add `Width: 100%` and `text-align: center`

```css
div.container {
 position: relative;
 height: 110px;
 width: 120px;
 border: dashed 1px red;
}

div.container div.text {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
 border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="text">
  <a href="#">Google.com</a>
 </div>

</div>
```

or `left: 0;`, `right: 0;` and `text-align: center;`

```css
div.container {
 position: relative;
 height: 110px;
 width: 120px;
 border: dashed 1px red;
}

div.container div.text {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
 border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="text">
  <a href="#">Google.com</a>
 </div>

</div>
```

```
or you can combine `margin-left: 50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%)`
```

```css
div.container {
 position: relative;
 height: 110px;
 width: 120px;
 border: dashed 1px red
}

div.container div.text {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 border: solid 1px black;
    margin-left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="text">
  <a href="#">Google.com</a>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
display:block;
margin:auto;
```

makes elements centered. So you could edit your code to become:

```
div.container div.text {
bottom: 0px;
border: solid 1px black;
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle because this is not working http://jsfiddle.net/r494Lx0r/5/

Comment: add these to div.text `position:absolute; left:0px;right:0px; text-align:center;` http://jsfiddle.net/r494Lx0r/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
.text{ width: 100%; text-align: auto; }
```

The text wrapping div will then be as wide as its container, so text align will work as expected.  The reason text-align isn't working for you on your current code is because the "text" div is only as wide as the link, therefore centering its contents does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

PROVIDED the link is the bottom/last element in the div-

add this to the div:

```
text-align: center; //centers the text
```

and then set the link to:

```
margin-top: auto; // pushes the text down to the bottom
```

worked in my case.

Simple and quick, but only works provided your link is the last element in the div.